# Suspend turns computer off, all opened windows/softwares are closed

Tags: suspend

I put my computer to suspend mode whenever I walk away. Whenever I return the computer boots quickly and I'm about to continue my work with all opened windows and softwares remaining open. Ever since I updated ubuntu today, when I suspend my computer it pretty much just shuts off.

Comment: I edited your question and removed your [tag:bug-reporting] tag because that has not been established yet, What version of Ubuntu are you currently using? What is the output of `lsb_release -a` Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497473/edit) your question and provide those details.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Each message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `man logger`.